# fix for log4j vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228) for Apache storm?

Tags: log4j, apache-storm, cve-2021-44228

There is no version of apache storm which doesn't use **log4j 2.x** version (which is affected by **CVE-2021-44228** vulnerability).

I found this fix on log4j website:
`you may remove the **JndiLookup** class from the classpath: zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`

but I am not sure whether doing this will have any other affect on my apache storm functionality, what if JndiLookup class is used by storm internally.

**What fix can I apply to my storm Installation (storm 2.2.0) for log4j vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228)?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent [Storm 2.4.0 release](https://storm.apache.org/2022/03/25/storm240-released.html) in March 2022 that addressed your concerns.

Alternatively, you can manually patch it using the principles of Java class loading mechanism:

1. Identify and download the official patches (and its dependencies) in this manner:
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j

   For convenience, direct link:

   - [log4j-core-2.17.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2/log4j-core-2.17.2.jar)
   - [log4j-api-2.17.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar)
   - [log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar)
2. Replace the libraries in `apache-storm-2.2.0/lib`:

   ```
   log4j-core-2.11.2.jar       --> log4j-core-2.17.2.jar      
   log4j-api-2.11.2.jar        --> log4j-api-2.17.2.jar       
   log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar --> log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar
   ```
3. Verify that the upgrade is successful:

   - Verify ANY/ALL log files are generated properly

     - Verify that `nimbus.log` file is generated properly
     - Negative test case is to remove the 3 libraries and `nimbus.log` will NOT be generated
   - The `nimbus.log` file prints out the 3 updated libraries in `o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.class.path=`